# How do I split my Jest + Puppeteer tests in multiple files?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jestjs, puppeteer

I am writing automated tests using Jest & Puppeteer for a Front-end application written in Vue.js

So far I managed to write a set of tests, but they all reside in the same file:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import faker from 'faker';

let page;
let browser;

const width = 860;
const height = 1080;
const homepage = 'http://localhost:8001/brt/';
const timeout = 1000 * 16;

beforeAll(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, // set to false if you want to see tests running live
    slowMo: 30, // ms amount Puppeteer operations are slowed down by
    args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`],
  });
  page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width, height });
});

afterAll(() => {
  browser.close();
});

describe('Homepage buttons', () => {
  test('Gallery Button', async () => {

    // navigate to the login view
    await page.goto(homepage);
    await page.waitFor(1000 * 0.5); // without this, the test gets stuck :(

    await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="navBarLoginBtn"]');
    await page.click('[data-testid="navBarLoginBtn"]'),

    await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="navBarGalleryBtn"]');
    await page.click('[data-testid="navBarGalleryBtn"]'),

    // test: check if we got to the gallery view (by checking nr of tutorials)
    await page.waitForSelector('.card-header');
    const srcResultNumber = await page.$$eval('.card-header', (headers) => headers.length);
    expect(srcResultNumber).toBeGreaterThan(1);
  }, timeout);
});

describe('Register', () => {
  const btnLoginToRegister = '#btn-login-to-register';
  const btnRegister = '#btn-register';
  const btnToLogin = '#btn-goto-login';

  test('Register failed attempt: empty fields', async () => {
    // navigate to the register form page via the login button
    await page.goto(homepage);
    await page.waitForSelector(navLoginBtn);
    await page.click(navLoginBtn);
    await page.waitForSelector(btnLoginToRegister);
    await page.click(btnLoginToRegister);

    // test; checking for error messages
    await page.waitForSelector(btnRegister);
    await page.click(btnRegister);
    const errNumber = await page.$$eval('#errMessage', (err) => err.length);
    expect(errNumber).toEqual(3);
  }, timeout);

  test('Register failed: invalid char count, email format', async () => {
    // fill inputs
    await page.waitForSelector('#userInput');
    await page.type('#userInput', 'a');
    await page.waitForSelector('#emailInput');
    await page.type('#emailInput', 'a');
    await page.waitForSelector('#emailInput');
    await page.type('#passInput', 'a');
    await page.waitForSelector(btnRegister);
    await page.click(btnRegister);

    // test: check if we 3 errors (one for each row), from the front end validations
    const err = await page.$$eval('#errMessage', (errors) => errors.length);
    expect(err).toEqual(3);
  }, timeout);

  test('Register: success', async () => {
    await page.click('#userInput', { clickCount: 3 });
    await page.type('#userInput', name1);
    await page.click('#emailInput', { clickCount: 3 });
    await page.type('#emailInput', email1);
    await page.click('#passInput', { clickCount: 3 });
    await page.type('#passInput', password1);
    await page.waitForSelector(btnRegister);
    await page.click(btnRegister);

    // test: check if go to login link appeared
    await page.waitForSelector(btnToLogin);
    await page.click(btnToLogin);

    // await Promise.all([
    //   page.click(btnToLogin),
    //   page.waitForNavigation(),
    // ]);
  }, timeout);

  test('Register failed: email already taken', async () => {
    // navigate back to the register form
    await page.waitForSelector(btnLoginToRegister);
    await page.click(btnLoginToRegister);

    await page.click('#userInput');
    await page.type('#userInput', name2);
    await page.click('#emailInput');
    await page.type('#emailInput', email1); // <- existing email
    await page.click('#passInput');
    await page.type('#passInput', password2);

    await page.click(btnRegister);

    const err = await page.$eval('#errMessage', (e) => e.innerHTML);
    expect(err).toEqual('Email already taken');
  }, timeout);
});
```

I would like to be able to have a single test file that does the beforeAll and afterAll stuff, and each test suite: HomepageButtons, Register, etc. to reside in it's own test file. How would I be able to achieve this?

I've tried splitting tets into:
testsUtils.js that would contain the beforeAll and afterAll hooks and code but it doesn't guarantee that it runs when it needs: the beforeAll code to fire before all other test files and the afterAll code to fire after all the test files finished.

Comment: read about Page Object Model: there are multiple tutorials on the web, including one with puppeteer + POM on udemy [link](https://www.udemy.com/automated-headless-browser-testing-with-puppeteer/)
read bout [node modules](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_modules.html)
then go with little bit advanced topic like [here](https://github.com/bencompton/jest-cucumber/blob/HEAD/docs/ReusingStepDefinitions.md)
Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I'd rather comment on your question, but I don't have reputation for that. Anyway, I think that you are looking for something like a "global beforeAll" and "global afterAll" hooks, right? Jest has it alread. It's called "globalSetup" and "globalTeardown".

Take a look at [globalSetup](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#globalsetup-string). Excerpt:

> This option allows the use of a custom global setup module which
>   exports an async function that is triggered once before all test
>   suites.

The Global Teardown one goes the same.
I think you'll have a headache trying to get a reference to the `page` or `browser` in globalSetup/globalTeardown and I confess that I never try this. Maybe the answer for that problem (if you have it) is on [this page](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer), under "Custom example without jest-puppeteer preset section.

Also there is a repo that tries to facilitate Jest + Puppeteer integration. Maybe you find it util: [repo](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer).

Good luck. :)